# How can I send a video using plugin codova plugin camera in ionic v1

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

How can I send a video or gif using plugin camera in ionic v1
I try with this code it shows me blank frame

```
$scope.gallery= function(){

  var options = {
  quality: 75,
  destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
  sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
  mediaType : Camera.MediaType.VIDEO
  };
  $scope.popover.hide()

  $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function (imageData) {

         $scope.imgURI = "data:video/mp4;base64," +imageData;
         console.log($scope.imgURI);
         sendImage($scope.imgURI);
         }, function (err) {
         // An error occured. Show a message to the user
         });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

can you please show sendImage method? To send gif or any file you will need Cordova file-transfer plugin.